# C++ Program taking control of terminal window

Tags: c++, linux, vim, terminal

When using vim in the terminal, it essentially blanks out the terminal's window and gives you a new one to start coding in, yet when you exit vim the terminal's previous output is still listed. How do you clear the terminal so that it only outputs your program's output, but returns to its normal state once the process has ended? (In linux, fedora)

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Preserve_screen#C or use ncurses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the low level, you send the terminal program a set of control characters that tell it what to do. This can be a bit too complex to to manage manually.

So instead, you might want to look at a console library like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which can manage all this complexity for you.

With respect specifically to the previous content magically appearing after the program exits, that's actually an xterm feature which vim is taking advantage of and which most modern terminals support. It's called "alternate screen" or simply "altscreen".  Essentially you tell the terminal program "Ok, now switch to a completely new screen, we'll come back to the other one later".

The command to switch to the alternate screen is typically `\E[?47h`, while the command to switch back is `\E[?47l`  For fun try this:

```
echo -e "\033[?47h"
```

and then to switch back:

```
echo -e "\033[?47l"
```

Or for a more more complete solution which relies a bit less on your shell to set things right (these are the sequences vim normally uses):

```
echo -e "\0337\033[?47h" # Save cursor position & switch to alternate screen
# do whatever

#Clear alternate screen, switch back to primary, restore cursor
echo -e "\033[2J\033[?47l\0338"
```

Comment: For various reasons, you probably want to use 1047, rather than just 47. Actually, better yet to use 1049, because that saves/restores the cursor position as well as the screen state.

Comment: @LeoNerd presumably you'd use termcap to find the most appropriate sequence for the terminal you're working with, though I really don't know where you'd go to find it. If you know have any additional information on the subject, I'd be happy to include it in this answer.

Comment: You presume incorrectly. termcap/terminfo haven't really caught up with many of the abilities of modern terminals. They know nothing of mouse, titles, extended colours beyond 8, ... Personally I work to a model that "all is like xterm" because, frankly, all terminals you're likely to encounter generally accept xterm-like control sequences.

Answer (score -2):

You can type "clear", or add a system command in your program to call "clear".  Also, if you're not aware, you can run system commands from inside vim, so you dont have to exit and type clear.  You can compile and run your programs from inside vim as well, for example ->

```
:!clear
:!make
:!./programName
```

Also, I never use this technique, but I believe you can have vim call a new terminal by using `:set terminal`

Comment: I think this is asking how to achieve the same effect in one's own program, not how to clear the screen from vim.